# Woocommerce before add to cart when product is out of stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have moved the product description before the variations (custom made) and before the add to cart button with the hook "*woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form*". It works great.

The problem is with products that are not i stock, then this hook does not seam to fire at all and the product description never shows.

How can I add the description before the variations but also on out of stock products?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this now, with two different codes. But the idea is to use only one hook for this. To use only *woocommerce_single_product_summary* places the description under the add to cart button.

This code adds the product description for products out of stock:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'visa_produktbeskrivning', 40 );
function visa_produktbeskrivning() {
global $product;
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
    echo '<div itemprop="description">';
        echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $product->description );
    echo '</div>';
}
}
```

And this code adds the product description for products in stock:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_custom_field' );
function display_custom_field() {

global $product;
    echo '<div itemprop="description">';
        echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $product->description );
    echo '</div>';
}
```